# How can I catch the incoming Message using HAPI Server

Tags: java, hapi

I'm really new on Hapi HL7 an used the example Server Class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HapiContext context = new DefaultHapiContext();
    MinLowerLayerProtocol mllp = new MinLowerLayerProtocol();
    mllp.setCharset("UTF-8");
    context.setLowerLayerProtocol(mllp);


    int port = 2010; // The port to listen on
    boolean useTls = false; // Should we use TLS/SSL?

    HL7Service server = context.newServer(port, useTls);

    ReceivingApplication handler = new ExampleReceiverApplication();


    server.registerApplication("*", "*", handler);
    server.registerConnectionListener(new MyConnectionListener());

    server.setExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler());

    server.startAndWait();

}
```

Now I want to catch the receiving message for further handle...
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at the example provided by HAPI

```
ReceivingApplication handler = new ExampleReceiverApplication();
```

This class can handle the incoming message

Comment: Hi,

danke für deine Antwort. Ich habe mittlerweile selbst die Lösung gefunden.

Ich habe mir einen eigenen Receiving Applikation Handler geschrieben und diesen wie folgt integriert.



server.registerApplication("ADT", "A01", new MyHandler());


Mein Handler orientiert sich nach dem Beispielhandler (Expample'), nur dass ich so auch die empfangenen Nachrichten auswerten kann.

Danke